# HIVE reports an error：Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.HadoopKerberosName.setRuleMechanism

Tags: linux, hive

When I use the bin/live command, I report an error. The HIVE version is 3.1.2, and the Hadoop version is 3.1.3
[This is the image information that reported an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmLDc.png)

I think it may be a jar package conflict. Have you ever encountered this situation